# Repeating cells in Table view - issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I am using a tableView to show a label, a button and an image. In my table which is bigger than 30 lines I have the issue of the button and image presenting wrong information as those are probably due to the well-known queueing mechanism methodology.

I read this article (https://fluffy.es/solve-duplicated-cells/) but even spending several hours testing it I cannot fix my problem. I tried hiding the button and image in my tableView function like this but doesn't work.

```
cell.cellBtn.isHidden = true
cell.cellImg.isHidden = true

let task = self.taskArray[indexPath.row]

if (task.done) {
    cell.cellBtn.isHidden = false
    cell.cellImg.isHidden = false
}
```

The problem is really focused only on the button and image which I change programmatically based on the customer selection. Here the basic code working well beside this queueing issue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LessonsVCCell
    
    
    cell.cellTitle.text = lessonsArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.cellDescription.text = lessonsArray[indexPath.row].details
    
    if lessonsArray[indexPath.row].blocked == 1 {
        
        cell.cellImg.isHidden = false
        cell.cellBtn.isHidden = false
        cell.cellImg.image = UIImage(systemName:"lock.fill")
        
        let cellImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image_name"))
        cellImg.setImageColor(color: UIColor.systemOrange)
        
    } else {
        cell.cellBtn.isHidden = true
        cell.cellImg.image = UIImage(named:"RightAnswerNew")
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

And the custom cell code ->

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellBtn: CustomButton2!
@IBOutlet weak var cellImg: UIImageView!

var cellDelegate: LessonsProtocol?
var index: IndexPath = []    
var chapter:[Chapter]?

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func buyBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    cellDelegate?.onClickCell(index: (index.row))
    
    
    
    if CommonClass.lessonBonus > 0 {
        if (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle == "Get" {
            CommonClass.lessonBonus -= 1
            CommonClass.NbOfLessonsSelected += 1
            
            cellBtn.setTitle("\(CommonClass.NbOfLessonsSelected)", for: .normal)
            cellBtn.backgroundColor = .green
            
        }
        else { // lesson already selected
            CommonClass.lessonBonus += 1
            CommonClass.NbOfLessonsSelected -= 1
            cellBtn.setTitle("Get", for: .normal)
            cellBtn.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }
    
        // if confirmation not ok for user
        if CommonClass.removeOnlyAllowed == 1 && (sender as AnyObject).currentTitle != "Get" {
            CommonClass.lessonBonus += 1
            CommonClass.NbOfLessonsSelected -= 1
            cellBtn.setTitle("Get", for: .normal)
            cellBtn.backgroundColor = .clear
            CommonClass.removeOnlyAllowed = 0
        }
}
```

Comment: any clue how I can progress on this issue?

Comment: I ***strongly suggest*** you start simple. With the code you posted, unfortunately, we have no idea what any of these are: `CustomButton2 LessonsProtocol Chapter CommonClass lessonsArray`. When you are getting started, you will find it **very** helpful to *comment* what you are expecting your code to do. Take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/2ke9vm9C

Comment: Sure, but globally is there an advice you can give on the generic question I posted. How to mange the queue and resetting it to avoid that my UIbutton and UIImage in further rows are showing wrong information?

Comment: Well, if you look at the comments I added to your code (https://pastebin.com/2ke9vm9C), you are setting `cellImg.isHidden = false` but there is nowhere it is set to `true` ... you're creating a ***NEW*** `cellImg` (`UIImageView`) but not doing anything with it. The best *"global advice for the generic question"* would be what I already said: **Start Simple** -- work with simple data until you can get a single element to show/hide properly, including when scrolling reusable cells.

Comment: I am trying to simplify the code but blocking on the solution how to get the index.row of the tableview (button tapped) in the custom cell code?

Comment: Edit your question, and show your simplified code... include enough detail so we can understand what you're trying to do (e.g. what is `CommonClass`?), and don't post "sort-of" code -- for example, in your current post, you have this line:  `cell.cellDescription.text = lessonsArray[indexPath.row].details` but your cell class code has no `cellDescription` element. Review [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is cells are reusable and when you scroll the table the cell passed away are reused for new appearance so for that we use a model to store the information of Passed cells. the problem with your code is you are changing the value of the Model in the table cell class which will not store the value of passed Cells so for that you can write the action of the button in the cellForRow Method like I have changed your code. please try like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
indexPath) as! LessonsVCCell


cell.cellTitle.text = lessonsArray[indexPath.row].name
cell.cellDescription.text = lessonsArray[indexPath.row].details

 if lessonsArray[indexPath.row].blocked == 1 {
    
    cell.cellImg.isHidden = false
    cell.cellBtn.isHidden = false
    cell.cellImg.image = UIImage(systemName:"lock.fill")
    
    let cellImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image_name"))
    cellImg.setImageColor(color: UIColor.systemOrange)
    
 } else {
    cell.cellBtn.isHidden = true
    cell.cellImg.image = UIImage(named:"RightAnswerNew")
 }
    // add these two lines 
    cell.cellBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.cellBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionChangeValue), 
    for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
 }

 @objc func actionChangeValue(_ sender:UIbutton){
   /* Do your Logic to change the value here and use sender.tag to 
   get the index of that particular cell */
 }
```

and remove the action of button from the UitableViewCell class